# Client HTTP Handling & ETag

Tags: c#, silverlight, caching, rest

I'm working on a small SilverLight application, which uses the WebClient to request a REST service. According to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=vs.95).aspx

no caching should be in place when using the 'Client HTTP' handling....

The REST service I'm calling use ETag, so with no Caching in place, I would not expect, that a second call to my service, would contain the If-None-Match header ??

Also when the REST service returns '304' (NotModified) I still get some data, indicating that the data is returned from the cache....

The REST service also sets the 'Vary' header to 'Accept' (so that the Accept header, should be taken into account when generating the Cache key), but is doesn't seem like this is working....

So I'm a bit confised, whether the caching is there or not.... seems like it's half-ways there...

Can someone clearify??

TIA

Søren

Comment: It really doesn't sound like you are actually using ClientHTTP, perhaps some code would help, especially in the area where you create the WebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using ETags on a WCF service.  In IIS, the service or the directory containing the service needs to include an HTTP response header setting the content to expire immediately so that there is no possibility of caching on the client.  This way a call to the service will not result in an HTTP 304 response from the server.